# Magento 2 : connect remote database over ssh tunnel

Tags: magento-2.1, database, ssh

I have a database setup on remote server that is accessible via SSH.
I need to connect magento 2 on my localhost to this mysql database via ssh tunnel.

- is this possible?
- if yes how?